# How can I add muti-dimensional array to laravel database

Tags: php, laravel

I want to store product option on my database and loop through it when I retrieve the data. The data structure takes a form

```
[
  {
    "color": "black",
    "extralCost": 100,
    "size": {
      "xs": 1,
      "sm": 4,
      "L": 2,
      "XL":6
    },
    "stock":13
  }, {
    "color": "white",
    "extralCost": 0,
    "size": {
      "xs": 1,
      "sm": 4,
      "L": 2
    },
    "stock":7
  },
  ...
]
```

I want to be able to store this in the database and retrieve it at the view.

Comment: I suggest you read how Models work as the answer is in there, you will learn a lot more than just asking one question after another on here.. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent

Comment: Look at [Array & JSON Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting).

Comment: I do understandand how models work. I don't want to separate the data. I just want to save a product options as a record in the database. I used json which worked but can't easily access the data in view when looping.

Comment: what problems do you face? please provide more details

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Model.

```
  protected $casts = [
    'column_name' => 'array',
];
```

To get an array:

```
$request->except('_token', '_method')
```

Comment: This is part of it, but the field needs to be set up to support it, too. It should be of the `json` field type in the migrations.

Comment: I used string type, just set it a size like:
 $table->string('my_array', 4096)->nullable(true);
But it's look like the data yor're getting from the form isn't in array format

Comment: The JSON field type has significant advantages over a long string. In some database engines, the JSON can be searched and indexed against more easily.